# Using Blazorise in Project Does Not Show menus

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazorise

I have used Visual Studio 2019 to create a Blazor server side project.
I then added Blazorise nuget to the project. 
I followed the Blazorise quick start to add in the using statements and style sheets and jquery and the registrations.
Unfortunately, once I did that, the project menu (ie Home, Counter, Fetch Data) no longer works.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm using .net core 3.1 and also tried 3.0.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a very broad question. The only answer would be something went wrong and you need to debug. By debugging I mean opening Chrome developer tools and check console for javascript errors.

Answer (score 2):

I see what the issue is now.
In the documentation, some css has to be manually copied into the headers of index.html or _Host.cshtml. I inserted these at the end of the headers but it created a problem.
Instead, I should have inserted it just before site.css stylesheet and let site.css be the last statement in the header. Then, everything started working fine.
Thanks everyone!